Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) in WSL
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
Hit:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot InRelease
All packages are up to date.
Summary:
Upgrading: 0, Installing: 0, Removing: 0, Not Upgrading: 0
14 not fully installed or removed.
Space needed: 0 B / 1,011 GB available

Setting up kismet-capture-nrf-mousejack (2023.07.R1-0kali6) ...
usermod: user '7' does not exist
dpkg: error processing package kismet-capture-nrf-mousejack (--configure):
installed kismet-capture-nrf-mousejack package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 6
Setting up kismet-capture-rz-killerbee (2023.07.R1-0kali6) ...
usermod: user '7' does not exist
dpkg: error processing package kismet-capture-rz-killerbee (--configure):
installed kismet-capture-rz-killerbee package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 6
Setting up kismet-capture-ti-cc-2531 (2023.07.R1-0kali6) ...
usermod: user '7' does not exist
dpkg: error processing package kismet-capture-ti-cc-2531 (--configure):
installed kismet-capture-ti-cc-2531 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 6
Setting up kismet-capture-nrf-51822 (2023.07.R1-0kali6) ...
usermod: user '7' does not exist
dpkg: error processing package kismet-capture-nrf-51822 (--configure):
installed kismet-capture-nrf-51822 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 6
Setting up kismet-capture-ubertooth-one (2023.07.R1-0kali6) ...
usermod: user '7' does not exist
dpkg: error processing package kismet-capture-ubertooth-one (--configure):
installed kismet-capture-ubertooth-one package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 6
Setting up kismet-capture-nrf-52840 (2023.07.R1-0kali6) ...
usermod: user '7' does not exist
dpkg: error processing package kismet-capture-nrf-52840 (--configure):
installed kismet-capture-nrf-52840 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 6
Setting up kismet-capture-ti-cc-2540 (2023.07.R1-0kali6) ...
usermod: user '7' does not exist
dpkg: error processing package kismet-capture-ti-cc-2540 (--configure):
installed kismet-capture-ti-cc-2540 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 6
Setting up kismet-capture-linux-bluetooth (2023.07.R1-0kali6) ...
usermod: user '7' does not exist
dpkg: error processing package kismet-capture-linux-bluetooth (--configure):
installed kismet-capture-linux-bluetooth package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 6
Setting up kismet-capture-nxp-kw41z (2023.07.R1-0kali6) ...
usermod: user '7' does not exist
dpkg: error processing package kismet-capture-nxp-kw41z (--configure):
installed kismet-capture-nxp-kw41z package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 6
Setting up kismet-capture-linux-wifi (2023.07.R1-0kali6) ...
usermod: user '7' does not exist
dpkg: error processing package kismet-capture-linux-wifi (--configure):
installed kismet-capture-linux-wifi package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 6
Setting up kismet-capture-hak5-wifi-coconut (2023.07.R1-0kali6) ...
usermod: user '7' does not exist
dpkg: error processing package kismet-capture-hak5-wifi-coconut (--configure):
installed kismet-capture-hak5-wifi-coconut package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 6
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kismet:
kismet depends on kismet-capture-hak5-wifi-coconut; however:
Package kismet-capture-hak5-wifi-coconut is not configured yet.
kismet depends on kismet-capture-linux-bluetooth; however:
Package kismet-capture-linux-bluetooth is not configured yet.
kismet depends on kismet-capture-linux-wifi; however:
Package kismet-capture-linux-wifi is not configured yet.
kismet depends on kismet-capture-nrf-51822; however:
Package kismet-capture-nrf-51822 is not configured yet.
kismet depends on kismet-capture-nrf-52840; however:
Package kismet-capture-nrf-52840 is not configured yet.
kismet depends on kismet-capture-nrf-mousejack; however:
Package kismet-capture-nrf-mousejack is not configured yet.
kismet depends on kismet-capture-nxp-kw41z; however:
Package kismet-capture-nxp-kw41z is not configured yet.
kismet depends on kismet-capture-rz-killerbee; however:
Package kismet-capture-rz-killerbee is not configured yet.
kismet depends on kismet-capture-ti-cc-2531; however:
Package kismet-capture-ti-cc-2531 is not configured yet.
kismet depends on kismet-capture-ti-cc-2540; however:
Package kismet-capture-ti-cc-2540 is not configured yet.
kismet depends on kismet-capture-ubertooth-one; however:
Package kismet-capture-ubertooth-one is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kismet (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kali-linux-headless:
kali-linux-headless depends on kismet; however:
Package kismet is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kali-linux-headless (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kali-linux-default:
kali-linux-default depends on kali-linux-headless; however:
Package kali-linux-headless is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kali-linux-default (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
kismet-capture-nrf-mousejack
kismet-capture-rz-killerbee
kismet-capture-ti-cc-2531
kismet-capture-nrf-51822
kismet-capture-ubertooth-one
kismet-capture-nrf-52840
kismet-capture-ti-cc-2540
kismet-capture-linux-bluetooth
kismet-capture-nxp-kw41z
kismet-capture-linux-wifi
kismet-capture-hak5-wifi-coconut
kismet
kali-linux-headless
kali-linux-default
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I got this error when I ran sudo apt install -y kali-linux-default after doing all the necessary installations on my laptop in WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) on Win11 Pro and after getting the error, if I run sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y, I get the same error and would need help on how to solve this error.

I'll do it for you now but in the future plese use the code tag to write your question.

After editing the markdown for you, your problem is User 7  When you created a non-root user did you create a user 7? Also, remember Kali Linux is used for Penetration Testing.  It should not be used as a daily linux system.
